# Codebehind (postback) vs Jquery with webservice (for saving data)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, security, performance

With regard to efficiency (speed) and security, which is better for saving data to db 1) using the regular way in codebehind (postback) or 2) jquery with webservice method ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparent speed - AJAX, but this will probably not be any quicker than a post-back, and may be slower depending on your method and process. But the speed to return process to the user AJAX is much better, and so it appears much faster. Of course, if you don't want user progressing and doing more work while the data is saving, this is a bad idea.

If you have a lot of inputs on your page and you only want to send a few of them for saving, then your transfer time will be less with an ajax call, just sending the relevant data. However, if you are sending most or all of the page data, then a postback will be very similar.

The real time consumer is the time to write data to the database ( as @Anthony Scott points out ), and if you do a postback, there is the data transfer time, the data write time and the redisplay page time before the page returns to usability. This can be significant.

As for security, there is no real difference, as they will both pass the same sort of data across the wire. If you are especially concerned about security, then you need to encrypt the data, whichever method you use.

Answer (score 3):

Saving to the db will be the same however you get the info to the web server. The efficiency comes from how much data you need to ship to the browser the rebuild the page afterwards.

Depending on how much information your page needs to send to the browser, how much of that comes from external data sources, how much processor cost there is in formatting the page etc etc etc.

If your page doesn't need to provide much feedback to the user about the update then a quick Ajax call might be a good idea. Even if your page does need to present slot of feedback / new data, then an Ajax call with an update of the page might still be a good idea.

I can't really be more specific than that given the information you've provided.

Comment: great . what if it is a form submission ?

Comment: It depends really, I don't profess to be an Ajax guru or anything, but it just comes down to what data you're sending each way and how much the page changes after thecform submission. There aren't any hard and fast rules (at least none I know of)

Comment: Sorry, it was one of those "it depends" answers :)